# Creating a anchor tag (hyperlink) in a javascript function (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm trying to create a hyperlink using javascript. Now please remember that this is being done in a function that is not necessarily related to the DOM. So the solutions with manipulating the DOM are not possible.

This is what I've come up with and when I output it, it just comes out as a string, the `anchor tag` is not interpreted.

```
        alert_message = 'Wrote a message on <a href="' + url_builder + '"> your profile</a>.';

        return alert_message;
```

and then `alert_message` is printed out onto the website. How can I force it to read the html tag? It just treats it as a string and I get the following output.

Output:

```
"Wrote a message on <a href="/members/tester/#kT6YkY8eDZdGDYQzQ"> your profile</a>."
```

Comment: The output-function (that prints the message) must be doing some escaping, in this case the `<` character. Did you look at the generated HTML-source?

Comment: @GitaarLAB I showed you the output in the message...

Comment: It's treated as "text". I put quotations around it to replicate what it shows in inspect element for chrome. 

It's not raw generated html, that's the whole point of this question really. It's coming out as a "string"... just text. I want to force the output to be html. The string it self is being sent to a div.

Comment: A string is a string, no matter what its contents are. Putting HTML elements in a string doesn't change that. I get the impression that you'd like the string to behave like HTML when logged into console - is that correct? Such behavior is not possible.

Comment: @HubertOG no... I don't think I said that. I want it to render as HTML on the webpage.

Here is a screenshoot of how it looks, don't want any more misinterpretations: http://i.imgur.com/ZaWJFDf.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings inserted using `{{helper}}` in Meteor templates are escaped by default, so embedded HTML will appear in the browser as plain text. You can use the `{{{helper}}}` (triple braces) to prevent this auto-escaping. In this case, you should be sure you're not opening yourself up to XSS.

Alternatively, you can make another template, something like:

```
<template name="wroteOnProfileAlert">
  <a href="/members/{{writer.username}}">{{writer.username}}</a>
  wrote a message on
  <a href="/members/tester/#{{user._id}}">your profile</a>
  <!-- if you're using Iron Router, use {{pathFor}} to generate URLs -->
</template>
```

You should prefer writing another template over generating HTML with string concatenation unless you have some specific reason.